# Получить остатки конкретного товара/комплекта через POS API

Tags: moysklad-pos-api

Задача: нужно получить остатки комплекта.

В jsonapi это сделать невозможно, как и посмотреть в онлайн мой склад. Но остатки комплектов выводятся в кассовой программе, отсюда мысль что их можно получить через POS API.

Вопрос как получить остатки конкретного товара по id либо по артикулу? или хотя бы отфильтровать online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/entity/assortment, по конкретному товару, так как в этом отчете есть остатки.

Прошу любую информацию как вытащить остатки комплектов. Или все же проще получить остатки по товарам в комплекте и по минимальному задать остаток?

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, апи не возвращает остатки по комплектам. Остатки по комплектам вы можете определить по остаткам компонентов (товаров) данного комплекта